# UTableView current visible cell indexPath.row

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want the indexPath.row of the current visible cell on the screen (currently I have the cell fill the entire screen so it should be just one)

```
print(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows)

//PRINT OUT
Optional([0, 0]) -row 0, screen just loaded
Optional([[0, 0], [0, 1]]) -row 1
Optional([[0, 1], [0, 2]]) -row 2
Optional([[0, 2], [0, 3]]) -row 3
Optional([[0, 2], [0, 3]]) -row 2 (scrolled back up)

print(tableView.visibleCells)
[]-not working
[]-not working
```

I tried the code above, but how do I get only the Y (row) number?  It also prints out the array when I scroll around. How do I get only the current visible cell?

I can't use cellForRowAt: indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You should try getting the center position of the table and then convert it to get the indexPath of the cell at that position. In `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  let visibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: CGPoint(x: tableView.bounds.midX, y: tableView.bounds.midY))
  // do whatever you want with your indexpath
}
```